# javascript: any UI libraries for building a search filtering frontend similar to ebay?

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface, javascript, javascript-framework

I'm building a search filtering frontend similar to eBay's. An example is [here](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Tops-Blouses-/53159/i.html?Size%2520%2528Women%2527s%2529=XS%7CS%7C0&Sleeve%2520Style=Short%2520Sleeve%7CSleeveless&Style=Blouse%7CKnit%2520Top&Color=Beiges%7CBlacks&rt=nc&_nkw=prada&_catref=1&_dcat=53159&_trksid=p3286.c0.m282).

As you can see, a user can filter search results on different facets: `size`, `color`, `style`, etc. For each facet a user can select multiple values, so for `size` she can select both `"XS"` & `"S"`. And a selected value can be deleted by the user by clicking on it, so click on the `"XS"` button and that value is no longer selected.

Is there any UI libraries/plugins/frameworks that can help in building such a frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out there are other variants of the same on this page.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_combobox.html